# JavaScript textarea

Tags: javascript, html

im new to js and have issues with following. I want the content of a html text input field to be displayed within a textarea via button click. I tried this:

```
.
.
function addText()
{
   var contentOfTxtField = document.getElementById("txtToGet").value;
   document.getElementById("idOfTheTextarea").innerHTML = contentOfTxtField;
}
.
.
```

Then I call my function in the onlick event of a button:

```
<button onclick="addText()">Add</button><br>
```

My problem is that the text shortly appears in the textarea but immediately disappears. Same for the entered text of the input text field. Any hints for me? Thk u

Comment: What? Immediately disappears? Is there anything else that affects the logic?

Comment: How does a <textarea> have innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the form is submitting, cancel the click event

```
<button onclick="addText(); return false;">Add</button><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace :

```
document.getElementById("idOfTheTextarea").innerHTML = contentOfTxtField;
```

By :

```
document.getElementById("idOfTheTextarea").textContent= contentOfTxtField;
```

**NOTE :** make sure that you're adding `type='button'` to the button since `button` tag act like submit by default.

Hope this helps.

---

**Snippet**

```js
function addText()
{
   var contentOfTxtField = document.getElementById("txtToGet").value;
   document.getElementById("idOfTheTextarea").textContent = contentOfTxtField;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value='example value' id="txtToGet"/>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="addText()">Add</button>
<br>
<textarea id='idOfTheTextarea'></textarea>
```